# This requires the 'super-parameters' language feature to be enabled - hive package

Tags: flutter, dart, hive

When I attempt to run `flutter pub run build_runner build` to generate my hive object, I face this error:

> This requires the 'super-parameters' language feature to be enabled.

Here is my flutter and dart SDK version:

[image]

and I also have tried flutter clean, flutter pub get and nothing happens actually.

Comment: Try to run `flutter upgrade`

Comment: I have the latest version of the Flutter: 3.0.5

Answer (score 1):

Ok, my problem's been solved :D
I remove my pubspec.lock and run a `flutter pub get` again and it is solved!